# Application opening on secondary monitor covers the top panel when moved to primary

Tags: linux, desktop-environment, monitors, multi-monitor

I am running an application (Think or Swim) that doesn't have a title bar, and it is now opening on the secondary monitor and covers the top panel (application does not resize, but stays fullscreen as on the secondary monitor) when it is moved to the primary monitor (laptop).

I did not have this issue before, but the application has started this behavior a couple days ago.

How could i force the application to open on the first monitor, or prevent it from covering the top panel?

Answer (score 0):

I am running Mate, and I changed window managers under Mate Tweak from Marco (software compositor) Marco (compton GPU compositor),

and it seems to have fixed the problem ...